# Implements Printable in Java

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, printing, awt

I'm getting this strange error for java printing.

```
2014-07-20 13:04:58.800 java[53716:d07] Cocoa AWT: Running on AppKit thread 0 when not expected. (
    0   libawt_lwawt.dylib                  0x00000001a6fefd0b nsPrintInfoToJavaPageFormat + 50
    1   libawt_lwawt.dylib                  0x00000001a6ff0500 Java_sun_lwawt_macosx_CPrinterJob_getDefaultPage + 51
    2   ???                                 0x000000010896fb7e 0x0 + 4439079806
    3   ???                                 0x000000010895b360 0x0 + 4438995808
    4   ???                                 0x000000010895b290 0x0 + 4438995600
)
```

I'm trying to print a simple page using this code:

```
PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
Book book = new Book();

book.append(new IntroPage(), printJob.defaultPage());

PageFormat documentPageFormat = new PageFormat();
documentPageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);

printJob.setPageable(book);

if (printJob.printDialog()) {
    try {
        printJob.print();
    } catch (Exception PrintException) {
        PrintException.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The thing is that this line `book.append(new IntroPage(), printJob.defaultPage());` is producing the error, the IntroPage() is implementing `Printable` and overrating the `print` method. This is the code:

```
public class IntroPage implements Printable {
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pageFormat, int page) {

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());
        g2d.setPaint(Color.black);

        Font titleFont = new Font("helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 8);
        g2d.setFont(titleFont);

        FontMetrics fontMetrics = g2d.getFontMetrics();

        g2d.drawString("Hello World!", 5, 10);

        return (PAGE_EXISTS);
    }
  }
```

**I'm using:**

```
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.0
Java: 1.8.0; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
System: Mac OS X version 10.9.2
```

Does anyone ever had this issue to help me how can I resolve it? I was searching about Netbeans bug's with no luck, and Mac OSX updates but my computer is already updated. Maybe I'm doing someting wrong on my code for `IntroPage`.

FYI:

- This is not working on Eclipse KEPLER (same error)
- I took the code from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/PrintinJavapageformatanddocument.htm)
- The example code is working perfectly when I copy/paste on new project in netbeans.
- I'm adding the code in to a javafx project.
- All of this is working perfect in Windows 8.